# Save Slack files in the folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, slack-api

I am cleaning up our Slack Account and want to save the files before deleting them. Attached is the script, which I got from github. Can someone please provide me a snippet I can add to the script so I can tell Python to save the files in the designated folder (root_folder). Please provide your kind assistance.

```
 from slacker import *
 import sys
 import time
 import os
 from datetime import timedelta, datetime

 root_folder = 'Z:\Slack_Files'

 def main(token, weeks=4):
     slack = Slacker(token)
     # Get list of all files available for the user of the token
     total = slack.files.list(count=1).body['paging']['total']
     num_pages = int(total/1000.00 + 1)
     print("{} files to be processed, across {} pages".format(total, num_pages))
     # Get Data about files
     files_to_save = []
     ids = [] # For checking that the API doesn't return duplicate files
     count = 1
    for page in range(num_pages):
    print ("Pulling page number {}".format(page + 1))
    files = slack.files.list(count=1000, page=page+1).body['files']
    for file in files:
        print("Checking file number {}".format(count))
        # Checking for duplicates
        if file['id'] not in ids:
            ids.append(file['id'])
            if datetime.fromtimestamp(file['timestamp']) < datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=weeks):
                files_to_save.append(file)
                print("File No. {} will be saved".format(count))
            else:
                print("File No. {} will not be saved".format(count))
        count+=1

print("All files saved\nProceeding to save files")
print("{} files will be saved!".format(len(files_to_save)))
count = 1
for file in files_to_save:
    print("Saving file {} of {} - {}".format(count, len(files_to_save), file["name"]))
    print(file["name"])
    count+=1

return count-1
```

Comment: is the API including details from files?

Comment: Is any of the code you posted your own, or is that directly from github? Are you asking us to write code for you when you have done no work on it yourself? If so, that's off-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes it includes details from our Slack Account. I have made additions to it. It is not exactly the same as github. I just want to tell Python to save the files in the designated folder. When I run the script, it returns a list of files that will be saved, I just need to add a snippet to save the files in the folder.

Comment: https://github.com/TetraEtc/slack-deleter/blob/master/file_deleter.py

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. If you have a specific issue I am sure people will be happy to help you. But don't expect people to do the coding for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic approach on how to do it.

1. Get the list of all files and their IDs with [files.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.list)
2. Loop through the list of all files
3. for each file: Use [files.sharedPublicUrl](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL) to get the public url for a file. Download and save it with your script. Finally delete it with [files.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.delete)

Note that your bot / access token will only be able to access files from private channels it / the corresponding user has been invited to.

Note further that your script need to respect the 1 request per second limit, or it will not run through.